# Simple border colors not working for IE7

Tags: html, css

```css
#skiptrace {
  border-top: #FFFFFF; 
  border-left: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: #FFFFFF;
  width: 731px;
  height: 900px; 
}
```

the border still appears on my div below in IE.

I'm trying to incorporate

```
<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">.pie, #skiptrace {behavior:url(PIE.htc);}</style><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
```

from this website.. which is pretty nice  http://css3pie.com/

```
<div id="skiptrace">
  <iframe name="my_iframe" src="" id="skiptrace"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes some kind of position like 'position:relative' makes pie work.

Comment: You can find some expations about the formatting on the right while editing. A limited set of html tags are also usable by SO but I would not recomment that.

Comment: Thanks rekire, I'll look into the formatting more, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using it this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
#skiptrace {
     border:1px solid #FFF;
     behavior:url(PIE.htc);
}
</style>
```

**NOTE:** PIE.htc is relative to **document** not the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for all the errors on my post... still figuring out the html and css on stack.. thanks for fixing, Cheers!

Comment: Still can't get it to work, it was in the header first (relative to the document)?? I tried adding it to the css as well like above but nothing seems to work.